# How can I collapse only one each time using @coreui-react?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, core-ui

Using the component `AppSidebarNav`, is it possible to only collapse once each time? I don't find anything in the documentation about that, some one already come to this problem?

my problem is: I have a lot of buttons with "childrens" (can collapse), and if the user click in serious buttons create a giant scroll bar, so how can I do with this component? Or I need to try another component?

I try to use the attributes but still not work.

```
    {
      name: 'user',
      icon: 'fa fa-building',
      children: [
        {
          name: 'Lista',
          url: '/user',
          icon: 'fa fa-bars',
          atributes:{"data-target":"toggle"}
        },
        {
          name: 'Adicionar',
          url: '/user/new',
          icon: 'fa fa-plus',
          atributes:{"data-target":"toggle"}
        },
      ],
    },
```

Comment: Would you mind showing us what you've tried already?

Comment: I add some code, this is the items the component render.

Answer (score 0):

I am using coreUI in a project and the AppSiderNav did not work well when I inserted a json query as a parameter to create the AppSideNav items .. I changed that component by MetisMenu .. and it works well ...